# Trying to reset my variables to their starting value javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

This is actually my first beginner project. I wrote the whole code myself. It's about buying phones through 3 different methods. You can tell the program to automatically buy all phones and phone masks for all money you got, to manually buy one by one or to enter a number of phones and masks you wanna buy. Together with all that I set a number of phones and masks available at the stop together with user's bank balance.

The problem's coming from eraseData function. It simply doesn't work. Actually, the first part of it works but the second where I'm trying to reset my variables to their original value isn't working.

I have problems with using this editor to put in my code so I will use Pastebin.

```
const PHONE_PRICE = 150.00;
const MASK_PRICE = 50;

var bankBalance = 1983;

var aPhones = 11;
var aMasks = 11;
var boughtPhones = 0;
var boughtMasks = 0;

function eraseData(){
    var bankBalance = 1800;

    var aPhones = 11;
    var aMasks = 11;
    var boughtPhones = 0;
    var boughtMasks = 0;
    var check = false;
    var quantity = 0;

    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money left: $" + bankBalance;
    document.getElementById("phones").innerHTML = "Amount of phones: " + boughtPhones;
    document.getElementById("masks").innerHTML = "Amount of phone masks: " + boughtMasks;
}

function updateData(){
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money left: $" + bankBalance;
    document.getElementById("phones").innerHTML = "Amount of phones: " + boughtPhones;
    document.getElementById("masks").innerHTML = "Amount of phone masks: " + boughtMasks;
}

checkOptions();

function checkOptions(){
    var check = prompt("There is three different ways to buy a phone. (A)utomatically, (M)anually and by (Q)uantity. Choose one option.")
    if(check == "A"){
        buyPhoneA();
    }
    else if(check == "M"){
        buyPhoneM();
    }
    else if(check == "Q"){
        buyPhoneQ();
    }
    else{
        alert("That's not a valid option!");
    }
}

function buyPhoneA(){
    alert("With this option you automatically spend all your money ($" + bankBalance.toFixed(2) + ") and buy all available phones and phone masks! (take in notice that you can't buy one if you don't have money for the other!)");
    var check = prompt("Type I AGREE if you agree to use this option!");
    if(check == "I AGREE" && aPhones >= 1 && aMasks >= 1 && bankBalance >= 200.00){
            while(bankBalance >= PHONE_PRICE + MASK_PRICE){
                aPhones--;
                aMasks--;
                boughtPhones++;
                boughtMasks++;
                bankBalance = bankBalance - PHONE_PRICE - MASK_PRICE;
                updateData();
                var check = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Something went wrong! Either you didn't type I AGREE correctly, we don't have phones left or you don't have enough money!");
        console.log(aPhones + " phones left");
        console.log(aMasks + " masks left!");
        console.log(boughtMasks + " bought masks!");
        console.log(boughtPhones + " bought phones!");
        console.log(bankBalance + " money left in the bank");
        checkOptions();
    }
}

function buyPhoneM(){
    alert("With this options we will ask your over and over again to buy a phone! You can decline or agree to buying a new one! No accessories included");
    var check = prompt("Type I AGREE if you agree to do this option!");
    if(check == "I AGREE" && bankBalance >= 150.00 && aPhones >= 1){
        aPhones--;
        boughtPhones++;
        bankBalance = bankBalance - PHONE_PRICE;
        updateData(); 
        buyPhoneM();
        var check = false;
    }
    else{
        alert("Something went wrong! Either you didn't type I AGREE correctly, we don't have any phones left or you don't have enough money!");
        checkOptions();
    }
}

function buyPhoneQ(){
    var quantity = 0;
    alert("With this option you will be asked to input a number of phones and accessories you want to buy!");
    var check = prompt("Type I AGREE if you agree to use this option!");
    if(check == "I AGREE"){
        var quantity = prompt("Input a number of how many phones and accessories you want to buy!")
        if(bankBalance >= 200.00 && aPhones >= 1 && aMasks >= 1){
            aPhones + aPhones - quantity;
            aMasks = aMasks - quantity;
            bankBalance = bankBalance - ((PHONE_PRICE + MASK_PRICE) * 2);
            boughtPhones = boughtPhones + quantity;
            boughtMasks = boughtMasks + quantity;
            updateData();
            var check = false;
        }
        else{
            alert("Something went wrong! Either the message your typed is not a number, you don't have enough money, we don't have enough masks or phones!");
            buyPhoneQ();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="money">Money left: $1800</p>
    <p id="phones">Amount of phones: 0</p>
    <p id="masks">Amount of phone masks: 0</p>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="eraseData();">Erase Data</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS's not really important for this..
(I don't remember why exactly put script tags below my button tag but I think it's because of something weird happening with my code, it didn't work until I did it that way )

I'd be grateful if anyone could help, thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, there is no `resetData` function in your Pastebin code.

Comment: Yeah, it's eraseData. Originally it was resetData so I made a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used global variable and local variables name same. 
Either rename the function variable different from global variables or remove **var** ahead of function variable.

Comment: Well, the idea was to use the global variable and keep using it through different functions, setting new values to it each time... How can I achieve that?

Comment: Tried your second solution but it didn't work. @user6447827